# JavaFX deployed application troubles with CSS styles

Tags: java, css, maven, netbeans, javafx

I created a JavaFX Maven application with some resources files (in project folder "src/main/resources"). The application works well in NetBeans environment. When the self-contained JAR file is built and I copy it to another folder, however, the application's visual items (ComboBoxes, TextFields, VBoxes, ...) are not displaying correctly (different colors, wrong padding, ...).

For example, [this screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/546bnj33oarbbxo/Good%20visualization.PNG?dl=0) shows a correct visualization (obtained in Netbeans environment) and [this screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v68zfqjc4ff2yff/Wrong%20visualization.PNG?dl=0) not. Here, the difference is the color of the ComboBox hovered items (which are white in the wrong version) and the size of the ComboBox bar. These styles are present in a CSS file (in "src/main/resources/styles").

I don't understand why the CSS is not being applied correctly in the deployed JavaFX Maven application. Some styles are still working (such as Buttons styles) but others not (such as ComboBoxes texts).

What should I do to prevent this happening?

**UPDATE:**

The CSS file is present in the JAR file because some styles (such as Buttons styles) are correctly loaded in the application (outside NetBeans). Here is the code I use to load the Stylesheet into the JavaFX Scene:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getResource("/styles/styles.css").toExternalForm());
```

The "styles.css" file is saved in "src/main/resources/styles/styles.css".

As an example, the following style is applied in Java code:

```
Button save = new Button("Save");
save.getStyleClass().add("primary-button"); // -> It works
```

Styles that do not work include those that do not have a direct styleclass. They affect all ComboBoxes, CheckBoxes, etc.. For instance:

```
.combo-box-popup {
    -fx-min-width: 555px;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view {
    -fx-min-width: 555px;
}

.combo-box-base  {
    -fx-background-color: transparent, transparent, transparent, white;
    -fx-border-width: 1;
    -fx-border-color: #666666;
    -fx-font-family: "Roboto Light";
    -fx-font-size: 14px;
    -fx-fill: #666666;
}

.combo-box .arrow {
    -fx-background-color: #979797;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}

.combo-box .arrow-button {
   -fx-background-color: #d8d8d8;
   -fx-background-radius: 0;
}

.combo-box .arrow-button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #e1e1e1;
    -fx-background-radius: 0;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:selected, .combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:selected:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #6995df;
}

.combo-box-popup .list-view .list-cell:filled:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
```

Netbeans IDE version: 8.0.1.

JavaFX version: 8 (from JDK 1.8.0_25).

Computer JRE version: 1.8.0_25.

I hope this helps to understand the problem.

Comment: Is the CSS present in the jar file? If so, maybe post the code you use to add the stylesheet to the scene.

Comment: I updated the question with more explanation, Java code and more CSS styles information. As I explained there, CSS troubles seem to be more frequent with "general" styleclasses (such as ".combo-box-popup", ".check-box", ".scroll-bar", ... ).

Comment: Are you running in different JDK versions in the different scenarios? There were some bugs preventing style being added properly to combo boxes in early JavaFX releases.

Comment: I updated Netbeans IDE to version 8.0.1 and JavaFX to version 8 (which is included in JDK 1.8.0_25). I checked the JavaFX version in code by using new classes only included in JavaFX 8 (such as TextFlow). My computer runs Java 8u25 but the problem is still the same.

Comment: Now the CSS problem also appears on NetBeans IDE with JavaFX 8! It seems that JDK 1.8.0_25 does not accept some styles (such as ".combo-box", ".scroll-bar", ...).

Comment: After making some changes in CSS file, I realized that JavaFX 8 has changed some features in CSS (such as backgrounds) and added some new default styles (such as white text in ComboBoxes). Finally, I changed and added some styles to my CSS file. Now, CSS works well. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After making some changes in CSS file, I realized that JavaFX 8 has changed some features in CSS (such as backgrounds) and added some new default styles (such as white text in ComboBoxes).

Finally, I changed and added some styles to my CSS file. Now, CSS works well. Thanks!